# Issue while sending message from preload.js to main.js using ipcRenderer and ipcmain

Tags: javascript, electron, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

i am beginner in desktop apps development with electron, when i try to send message from preload script to main.js using ipcRenderer and ipcMain in main.js below details shows up in VScode terminal and nothing happens(no event occurs) not even console.log works

```
{
  preventDefault: [Function: preventDefault],
  sender: EventEmitter {
    isDestroyed: [Function: isDestroyed],
    destroy: [Function: destroy],
    getBackgroundThrottling: [Function: getBackgroundThrottling],
    setBackgroundThrottling: [Function: setBackgroundThrottling],
    getProcessId: [Function: getProcessId],
    getOSProcessId: [Function: getOSProcessId],
    equal: [Function: equal],
    _loadURL: [Function: _loadURL],
    reload: [Function: reload],
    reloadIgnoringCache: [Function: reloadIgnoringCache],
    downloadURL: [Function: downloadURL],
    getURL: [Function: getURL],
    getTitle: [Function: getTitle],
    isLoading: [Function: isLoading],
    isLoadingMainFrame: [Function: isLoadingMainFrame],
    isWaitingForResponse: [Function: isWaitingForResponse],
    stop: [Function: stop],
    canGoBack: [Function: canGoBack],
    goBack: [Function: goBack],
    canGoForward: [Function: canGoForward],
    goForward: [Function: goForward],
    canGoToOffset: [Function: canGoToOffset],
    goToOffset: [Function: goToOffset],
    canGoToIndex: [Function: canGoToIndex],
    goToIndex: [Function: goToIndex],
    getActiveIndex: [Function: getActiveIndex],
    clearHistory: [Function: clearHistory],
    length: [Function: length],
    isCrashed: [Function: isCrashed],
    forcefullyCrashRenderer: [Function: forcefullyCrashRenderer],
    setUserAgent: [Function: setUserAgent],
    getUserAgent: [Function: getUserAgent],
    savePage: [Function: savePage],
    openDevTools: [Function: openDevTools],
    closeDevTools: [Function: closeDevTools],
    isDevToolsOpened: [Function: isDevToolsOpened],
    isDevToolsFocused: [Function: isDevToolsFocused],
    enableDeviceEmulation: [Function: enableDeviceEmulation],
    disableDeviceEmulation: [Function: disableDeviceEmulation],
    toggleDevTools: [Function: toggleDevTools],
    inspectElement: [Function: inspectElement],
    setIgnoreMenuShortcuts: [Function: setIgnoreMenuShortcuts],
    setAudioMuted: [Function: setAudioMuted],
    isAudioMuted: [Function: isAudioMuted],
    isCurrentlyAudible: [Function: isCurrentlyAudible],
    undo: [Function: undo],
    redo: [Function: redo],
    cut: [Function: cut],
    copy: [Function: copy],
    paste: [Function: paste],
    pasteAndMatchStyle: [Function: pasteAndMatchStyle],
    delete: [Function: delete],
    selectAll: [Function: selectAll],
    unselect: [Function: unselect],
    replace: [Function: replace],
    replaceMisspelling: [Function: replaceMisspelling],
    findInPage: [Function: findInPage],
    stopFindInPage: [Function: stopFindInPage],
    focus: [Function: focus],
    isFocused: [Function: isFocused],
    sendInputEvent: [Function: sendInputEvent],
    beginFrameSubscription: [Function: beginFrameSubscription],
    endFrameSubscription: [Function: endFrameSubscription],
    startDrag: [Function: startDrag],
    attachToIframe: [Function: attachToIframe],
    detachFromOuterFrame: [Function: detachFromOuterFrame],
    isOffscreen: [Function: isOffscreen],
    startPainting: [Function: startPainting],
    stopPainting: [Function: stopPainting],
    isPainting: [Function: isPainting],
    setFrameRate: [Function: setFrameRate],
    getFrameRate: [Function: getFrameRate],
    invalidate: [Function: invalidate],
    setZoomLevel: [Function: setZoomLevel],
    getZoomLevel: [Function: getZoomLevel],
    setZoomFactor: [Function: setZoomFactor],
    getZoomFactor: [Function: getZoomFactor],
    getType: [Function: getType],
    _getPreloadPaths: [Function: _getPreloadPaths],
    getLastWebPreferences: [Function: getLastWebPreferences],
    getOwnerBrowserWindow: [Function: getOwnerBrowserWindow],
    inspectServiceWorker: [Function: inspectServiceWorker],
    inspectSharedWorker: [Function: inspectSharedWorker],
    inspectSharedWorkerById: [Function: inspectSharedWorkerById],
    getAllSharedWorkers: [Function: getAllSharedWorkers],
    _print: [Function: _print],
    _printToPDF: [Function: _printToPDF],
    _setNextChildWebPreferences: [Function: _setNextChildWebPreferences],
    addWorkSpace: [Function: addWorkSpace],
    removeWorkSpace: [Function: removeWorkSpace],
    showDefinitionForSelection: [Function: showDefinitionForSelection],
    copyImageAt: [Function: copyImageAt],
    capturePage: [Function: capturePage],
    setEmbedder: [Function: setEmbedder],
    setDevToolsWebContents: [Function: setDevToolsWebContents],
    getNativeView: [Function: getNativeView],
    incrementCapturerCount: [Function: incrementCapturerCount],
    decrementCapturerCount: [Function: decrementCapturerCount],
    isBeingCaptured: [Function: isBeingCaptured],
    setWebRTCIPHandlingPolicy: [Function: setWebRTCIPHandlingPolicy],
    getWebRTCIPHandlingPolicy: [Function: getWebRTCIPHandlingPolicy],
    takeHeapSnapshot: [Function: takeHeapSnapshot],
    setImageAnimationPolicy: [Function: setImageAnimationPolicy],
    _getProcessMemoryInfo: [Function: _getProcessMemoryInfo],
    id: 1,
    session: [Getter],
    hostWebContents: [Getter],
    devToolsWebContents: [Getter],
    debugger: [Getter],
    mainFrame: [Getter],
    _windowOpenHandler: null,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      '-ipc-message': [Function (anonymous)],
      '-ipc-invoke': [Function (anonymous)],
      '-ipc-message-sync': [Function (anonymous)],
      '-ipc-ports': [Function (anonymous)],
      crashed: [Function (anonymous)],
      'render-process-gone': [Function (anonymous)],
      'devtools-reload-page': [Function (anonymous)],
      '-new-window': [Function (anonymous)],
      '-will-add-new-contents': [Function (anonymous)],
      '-add-new-contents': [Function (anonymous)],
      login: [Function (anonymous)],
      'ready-to-show': [Function (anonymous)],
      'select-bluetooth-device': [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    _eventsCount: 13
  },
  frameId: 1,
  processId: 4,
  reply: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

on button click a function from preload will be called which will send message to main processs

renderer.js

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.LoadProductWindow.load();
});
```

preload.js

```
const {
    contextBridge,
    electron,
    ipcRenderer
} = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('LoadProductWindow', {
    load: () => ipcRenderer.send('load_product_window')
})
```

main.js

```
ipcMain.on('load_product_window', () => {
    console.log('received')
});
```

please solve my issue and also i want to add a new window on button click to add new items how can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: no errors in console? What's with the `{ electron }` import? You don't need that, right?

Comment: no errors just the above mentioned script. not using in shown code but will use it. yeah don't need that as far as this is concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no doubt that many examples showing the use of
Electron's [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) and `preload.js` are
complicated and difficult to understand. Once you have a firm understanding
of [Context-Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation) then things will begin to fall
into place.

The main issue I have been finding recently is that many people are breaking
the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) design principle with
their `preload.js` script. Whilst this is not a hard and fast rule, simplifying your `preload.js` script by moving all
logic out of it apart from pure communication logic makes for really simple, readable code.

---

First off, let's define a simple, easy to read `preload.js` script.

In this script you will find an `ipc` object containing 3 arrays (`send`, `receive` and `sendReceive`) where you can
define your [white-listed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelisting) channels names. When called from either the main
thread or render thread, they will pass without be obstructed. Any and all other channel names used which are not
defined within these 3 arrays will be blocked.

Here, I have added the channel name `productWindow:load` to the `send` (from render to main thread) array.

`preload.js` (main thread)

```js
'use strict';

// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [
            'productWindow:load'
        ],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

Next, we will quickly define your `index.html` file which will include Javascript functionality to send an IPC message
to the main thread upon the push of a button.

`index.html` (render thread)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Main Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <label for="button">Product Window: </label>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Load Now">
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRender.send('productWindow:load');
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

---

`product.html` (render thread)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Product Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>It Works..!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Finally, in your `main.js` script (being the entry point of your application) we listen for a message over
the `productWindow:load` channel using Electron's [`ipcMain`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main)
module, specifically the [`ipcMain.on()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main#ipcmainonchannel-listener)
method.

`main.js` (main thread)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require("path");

let mainWindow;
let productWindow;

function createMainWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { mainWindow.show(); });

    return mainWindow;
}

function createProductWindow(parentWindow) {
    const productWindow = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        parent: parentWindow,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    productWindow.loadFile('product.html')
        .then(() => { productWindow.show(); });

    return productWindow;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = createMainWindow();
});

// Let's listen for the 'productWindow:load' signal.
electronIpcMain.on('productWindow:load', () => {
    productWindow = createProductWindow(mainWindow);
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createMainWindow();
    }
});
```

As your Electron application begins to grow you will want to begin splitting your `main.js` file into smaller files,
to 'separate your concerns'. IE: Moving your different window creation code segments into their own files, including their associated IPC code.

This will improve your code structure, simplify readability and make for a maintainable
code base.

Comment: It worked, thank you.Why isn't that strategy documented in the official docs?
Who should I consult in order to finish my application and gain a firm understanding of electron concepts?

Comment: I'm confused. Besides the whitelisting changes, how is this different from what Aaqib was doing? Like what exactly fixes the issue?

Comment: @pushkin On the surface, nothing is different. But underneath, there could be a number of issues not documented in the question causing the bug. Gauged by the OP's rep at the time of questioning, by clearly outlining the issue of separating concerns in the `preload.js` script and proper positioning of module methods within the `main.js`, the OP with hopefully better understand the overall structure required to achieve working code. Many people are struggling with the implementation of IPC. By defining a relevant well structed example, it helps the OP better understand the larger picture.

Answer (score 0):

the first argument in the message to an IPC is the EVENT object,
to get your object you needed to do it like this

```
ipcMain.on('myMessage',(event, myObj) => {
    console.log(myObj)
});
```